# how to fix a IE8 error with an older version of tablesorter jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to fix some bugs with a site that was developed a few years ago, with an older version of jquery. This particular problem only occurs in IE8, in the jquery.tablesorter.min.js script. I don't know how to tell what version of tablesorter is used from the minified version, but the version of jquery is 1.3.2.  Here is the error:

```
Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
Line: 2
Char: 6697
```

it is in this section of the line:

```
function getCachedSortType(parsers,i){return parsers.type;};
```

The body of the table that uses tablesorter is empty on this page (it can have rows added to it). It still has the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags. I read at [another forum post on the same problem](http://www.websitebaker2.org/forum/index.php?topic=18942.0) that the problem could be related to the position of the `<table>` and `<form>` tags. They say that the table which uses the tablesorter must be inside the form, which it is on this page.

However, this controller's layout also contains `<table>` tags, and the form for this particular page with the tablesorter table is located within the layout `<table>`.  Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: user26270, did you ever find a solution to this?